# Cannot create directory inside a docker container. Permissions trouble

Tags: php, symfony, docker

I'm trying to deploy symfony application within docker. Now I have a trouble with permissions on Linux server. On my local Mac everything ok. 
I have `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3'

volumes:
  . :
services:
  db:
    image: mysql
    volumes:
      - "./.data/db:/var/lib/mysql"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DATABASE_ROOT_PASS}
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${DATABASE_NAME}
      MYSQL_USER: ${DATABASE_USER}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${DATABASE_PASS}
  php:
    build: ./docker/fpm
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/app
  nginx:
    build: ./docker/nginx
    ports:
      - ${APP_PORT}:8080
    volumes:
      - ./.logs/nginx/:/var/log/nginx
      - ./:/var/www/app
```

And Dockerfile for `php` image:

```
FROM php:7.1-fpm-alpine

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
RUN composer --version

RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
USER www-data
WORKDIR /var/www/app
```

So everything building ok, but when after I trying to run `docker-compose exec php composer install` I got the error:
`/var/www/app/vendor does not exist and could not be created.`

Why it happens only on a linux server?

I'm running `$ docker-compose up` from user `myapp`.

**UPD**:
Looks like `chown` is not working correctly:

`$ docker-compose exec php ls -l /var/www/app`:

```
total 168
-rw-r--r--    1 40007    40007         1662 Apr 19 08:44 Makefile
...
```

The owner is not `www-data`

**UPD2**: 
I think the reason is that after we mount `volume` from the docker-compose file, it takes the rules from that volume, so that's why `chown` has not had an effect.

This is a reason. But what a beautiful solution for it?

Comment: Your workdir is `/var/app`, but you chown `/var/www`. Maybe that's the issue?

Comment: just a typo in the question, I fixed it.

Comment: Have you tried to create user `USER www-data` before doing RUN chown? Anyway, I see that you're doing chown and user creation in **building** phase, and volumes are mounted in get **up** / **run** /deploy service phase.

Comment: @AlexGalera yeah, I think that is the reason. Do you know a good solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User IDs inside container and outside in a volume are the same numerically (unless your docker daemon is configured with user namespaces) but can easily have different names. If you want to match the user on the host then use the numeric ID. You *should* also set the group.

In a Dockerfile build a RUN chown **only** affects the files that go into the image, **not** the files that are added in runtime with a bind mount. The bind mount will also obscure files added inside the container image at build time.

If the volume owner varies across systems then introduce a build-arg in your Dockerfile.

```
ARG volumeOwnerGroup
USER $volumeOwnerGroup
```

Do build with: `--build-arg volumeOwnerGroup=$(stat -c '%u:%g' /var/www/app)`

In a docker-compose file you can set build-args with the `args` dictionary. You can pull values for that from a `.env` file in the same directory as the  `docker-compose.yml`. Then you only have to make sure the `.env` file fits your machine. See also https://vsupalov.com/docker-env-vars/.

Comment: It did not help. Actually, the directory exists: `docker-compose exec php ls /var/www/app` shows me all app directories

Comment: look on upd in the question

Comment: Can you run `docker-compose exec id www-data`

Comment: `uid=82(www-data) gid=82(www-data) groups=82(www-data),82(www-data)`

Comment: Try a RUN `chown -R 82:82` in dockerfile

Comment: it's didn't help

Comment: What is the numeric ID on the /var/www/app directory on the host? `ls -n /var/www/app`

Comment: `echo $UID;
40007`

Comment: Then try USER 40007

Comment: yes! that works fine. but looks like this is not a flexible solution. can I use something like this: `USER $UID`?

Comment: yeah, just `USER $UID` works fine. tnx. can you edit your answer with final solution?

Comment: Uhm, I suspect that `USER $UID` will be replaced with `USER 0` ergo root,  unless you are running the compose with another user and then it will fail again.

Comment: Hm... You're right. But what solution to pass current userid to Dockerfile?

Comment: I think this is excellent material: https://vsupalov.com/docker-env-vars/ 
You could do a stat -c '%u:%g' /var/www/app > .env before you invoke docker-compose (or use a small wrapper script)  and an 'args' block in your compose.yml feeding the ARG inside the Dockerfile.

Comment: `export UID` and in then in `docker-compose.yaml`: `user: $UID` works fine. tnx

Comment: That would probably mean you are still running the process in the container with root. That user will have no permission problem, but this is probably not what you actually want.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
FROM php:7.1-fpm-alpine

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
RUN composer --version

RUN mkdir -p /var/www/app \
 && chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
USER www-data
WORKDIR /var/www/app
```